# Adding Interval to Timestamp without using a literal

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a Timestamp column that I would like to add minutes to without using a literal. I would like to use the value from another column to apply to the Timestamp column. The minutes to add will always be in the same row as the timestamp they are to be added to.

The resulting column (SCAN_DTM_ADJ) should look like this:

```
SCAN_DTM_UTC                           TIME_DELTA(SMALLINT)                  SCAN_DTM_ADJ
2020-01-20 19:28:59.000000                 5                   2020-01-20 19:33:59.000000
2020-01-20 19:14:00.000000                 2                   2020-01-20 19:16:00.000000
2020-01-20 14:49:14.000000                 1                   2020-01-20 14:50:14.000000 
2020-01-17 15:51:00.000000                 7                   2020-01-17 15:58:00.000000
2020-01-17 12:52:57.000000                10                   2020-01-17 13:02:57.000000
```

How would this be done?

Many thanks

Comment: Column TIME_DELTA data type?

Comment: TRy `SCAN_DTM_UTC + cast(TIME_DELTA as interval minute)`, assuming TIME_DELTA  is integer.

Comment: Or perhaps simply `SCAN_DTM_UTC + TIME_DELTA`, if TIME_DELTA is interval minute.

Comment: `SCAN_DTM_UTC + (TIME_DELTA * INTERVAL '0000 00:01'  DAY TO MINUTE)` allows adding up to 14 milion minutes